# Large negative hex value conversion to long in java

Tags: java, string, hex, long-integer

the result should have a negative value, but its positive.

How can I fix this?

Thanks!!

BigInteger b = new BigInteger("80000000000000004308000000000000", 16);

System.out.println("long value: "+b.longValue());

-->
long value: 4830110600354856960

Comment: I do not understand, why should it be negative?

Comment: @Nican His number actually starts with the 4 and does fit into a long. I think the 8 at the start is an attempt to denote a sign using two's complement.

Comment: @JeffFerland The BigNumber constructor specified if a number is suppose to be negative, you have to put the optional "-" sign in front.

Comment: @Nican I detailed that constrictor issue in my answer below. Just theorizing on why the asker expects a negative value.

Answer (score 1):

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5,0/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#longValue%28%29

See the above page to understand why it won't be negative. It returns the low 64bits, so your last 64 bits must be higher than Long.MAX_VALUE to cause a negative value.

Answer (score 1):

Your string representation is a signed long but is being presented to BigInteger as an unsigned string (sign is denoted by using a "-" at the start of your string).

> [The String representation consists of an optional minus sign followed by a sequence of one or more digits in the specified radix.](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5,0/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#BigInteger%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)

Bit shifting or correcting your string is needed to make this work from a string instantiation.

I think the best answer is to convert your string to a byte array and use the [BigInteger(byte[] val)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5,0/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#BigInteger%28byte%5B%5D%29) instantiation which will recognize a negative or positive number based on two's complement. [Many options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/140131/convert-a-string-representation-of-a-hex-dump-to-a-byte-array-using-java) exist for that string to byte array conversion. Take your pick.

... oh, and your number is too large to fit into a long, so that's going to be an issue too; you get the least significant bits.

Answer (score 0):

If you always have 128-bit numbers and assume the highest bit is your sign then you can use the following lines:

```
BigInteger neg = BigInteger.ONE.shiftLeft(127);
BigInteger b = new BigInteger("80000000000000004308000000000000", 16);
if(b.compareTo(neg) >= 0) { 
    b = neg.subtract(b); 
}
```

Note: `b.longValue()` will only be appropriate if the number of bits fits into a long which may not be the case for such large numbers.